# How to associate a lua_sethook context with lua_sethook?

Tags: c, debugging, lua, hook, lua-api

I'm trying to write a debugger for a process running lua scripts, and the documented way of doing so (in C) is to use `lua_sethook`:

```
int lua_sethook (lua_State *L, lua_Hook f, int mask, int count);
```

`lua_Hook` is defined as:

```
typedef void (*lua_Hook) (lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar);
```

The hook only gets a `lua_State` pointer, which is great, but how can I associate a pointer to my debugger class with it so that I can get back into my debugger class from there?

I would like to avoid using a global variable in this case as I have multiple `lua_State` instances. I suppose I could use a map of `lua_State *` pointers to debugger instances, but that doesn't seem efficient. And storing it as a global in the `lua_State *` doesn't seem to make sense because in order to be able to retrieve it, I would have to push at least one value onto the lua stack, which seems hard/impossible to do in the case of a lua stack overflow.

Am I missing something?  How would I accomplish this? I know, I could accomplish this in lua code, but I would like to understand how I can do this from the C side.

Comment: What's the multiplicity relationship between your debugger class and `lua_State`? For example, can we assume for a given `lua_State` there can be at most one debugger class? Can a debugger class be shared between several `lua_State` or does each `lua_State` get its own unique indepedent debugger class?

Comment: In my case it is a 1:1 relationship.  The debugger class has the pointer to one lua_State*, and I need to effectively be able to get from the lua_State* to the debugger class in the lua_Hook function somehow.

Comment: What about storing it in the lua registry? You'll still have to push it onto the stack in your `hook` function but I'm not sure why you have to worry about it overflowing. Can't you just do a `lua_checkstack` and if it does fail just handle it in your C code?

Comment: I suppose I could do that.  For now I am maintaining a map of state pointers to debuggers.  It's not ideal, but since all the scripts run in the same thread I can get away without any locks.  I was hoping there was a more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you cannot directly associate a value with a hook function.

But you can indirectly do so in a variety of ways. The safest is probably to put the value in a known location within the Lua registry. You could also make it a global. But however you do it, it needs to be something that can be accessed through the `lua_State` object.

Using data external to the registered Lua instance is dangerous. That is, you might conceivably have an associative container that maps `lua_State` pointers to registered instance data. However, if you try this, it may fail if your hook function is called during the execution of a Lua coroutine, since they have separate `lua_State` objects from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there's an extra space in `lua_State`, which you can get it with `lua_getextraspace`. And it is not touched by Lua itself, according to the manual. By default its size is `sizeof(void*)`. So maybe you can allocate a self-defined structure after `lua_newstate`, use it in the debug hook, and free it before `lua_close` by yourself.